# How to push IPA and APK file to App Center Distribute from appcenter command line and Jenkins

Tags: android, ios

How to push an iOS IPA file and Android APK file to App Center Distribute from the command line? Then I would like to execute appcenter command in Jenkins and upload the ipa and apk file.

I installed the npm appcenter-cli at RHEL 
$ appcenter -v
appcenter version 1.1.14

I am using the following command at unix prompt , I put it my ipa and apk file in /tmp directory and provided full access. 
$ appcenter login --token e************************88cb4
Logged in as 
$ appcenter distribute release -f /tmp/20190322P.ipa -g Collaborators --app ***/Pradeep.iOSDev--ios

but getting below mentioned error
Error: failed to create release upload for /tmp/20190322P.ipa

I followed the followings urls
[How to push IPA to App Center Distribute from Continuous Integration Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50361860/how-to-push-ipa-to-app-center-distribute-from-continuous-integration-server)
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/appcenter/cli/

Please suggest me how to upload ipa and apk files from appcenter command line and then execute in Jenkins.

Comment: I resolved this issue and I run the following command. appcenter distribute release -f $IPAFile -g Collaborators --app <username/<foldername>, and for APK file I run the following command. appcenter distribute release -f $APKFile -g Collaborators --app <username/<foldername>

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to push IPA to App Center Distribute from Continuous Integration Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50361860/how-to-push-ipa-to-app-center-distribute-from-continuous-integration-server)

Answer (score 0):

In my case the issue was that app had **Store** Release Type.

Changed it to **Enterprise** and then it worked like a charm.

(to get the idea of the issue cause, after googling didn't help, I have executed `appcenter distribute release` with `--debug` flag, and the output contained the explanation).